# Фильтр вывода записей с базы

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос возник, допустим, я имею таблицу id и name, есть 3 поля с именами Вася, Петя, Вася, и вот как сделать запрос, чтобы он не повторял одни и те же имена, то есть чтобы вывел Вася Петя и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM 'table' GROUP BY 'column'
```

column - колонка, в которой НЕ нужно выводить повторы.

Comment: Благодарю

Comment: палец вверх+принять ответ лучшая благодарность.

Comment: группировка не для этого придумана. distinct правильный ответ

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct name from table
```

Если нужен id, то требуется уточнение, у какого васи его взять. Если у первого, то тогда так:

```
select min(id), name from table group by name
```

Comment: а если у второго?

Comment: Тогда max(id). А если вам нужен конкретный вася, то тогда по id его и отбирайте. :-)